# How to set filter range in backend in filter class in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm building a REST API using DRF. I'm using django_filters for filtering result set. In one api I want user to send his coordinates(latitude, longitude) and in backend I create a range as (latitude+2 to latitude-2) and return results, I don't want take range field from user. So I can easily change the range in my backend.

I've created two range filters in filter class that works fine but url looks like this: /posts/?latitude_min=22&latitude_max=28&longitude_min=80&longitude_max=84. And here user is responsible to decide range. I want user send latitude and longitude only, I decide about maximum and minimum range.

```py
class PostFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    latitude = django_filters.RangeFilter(field_name='latitude')
    longitude = django_filters.RangeFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['latitude', 'longitude', 'country', 'state', 'district', ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use 'MethodFilter' something like this:

```py
from django.db.models import Q

class PostFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    latitude = django_filters.MethodFilter(action="filter_latitude")
    longitude = django_filters.MethodFilter(action="filter_longitude")

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['latitude', 'longitude', 'country', 'state', 'district']

    def filter_latitude(self, qs, value):
        try:
            return qs.filter(Q(latitude__gte=value-2)&Q(latitude__lte=value+2))
        except BaseException:
            return qs 

    def filter_longitude(self, qs, value):
        try:
            return qs.filter(Q(longitude__gte=value-2)&Q(longitude__lte=value+2))
        except BaseException:
            return qs
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, MethodFilter are now deprecated and are replaced with Filter.method (https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/migration.html#methodfilter-and-filter-action-replaced-by-filter-method)

Comment: I'm going through new documentation, and trying to implement it. Will update you in sometime if it works. Thanks

Comment: I used Number filter as: ```latitude = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='latitude', method='filter_latitude')``` and in filter_latitude method I passed additional argument name as 'latitude' as ``` def filter_latitude(self, qs, latitude, value):```

Comment: Can you tell me how to use name field inside filter_latitude method as well?

Comment: Please post your filter class to gist and attach link here. I want see all class

Comment: Gist link: https://gist.github.com/Vishal7Sharma/ff0915da0e54d605bf1f8d6719519262

Comment: See [comment](https://gist.github.com/Vishal7Sharma/ff0915da0e54d605bf1f8d6719519262#gistcomment-3021067)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I have question how filter_coordinate method taking name field automatically? even without passing name of variable?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom filter field that does this, in just a few lines of code.  It will give you a bit more flexibility to add validation later as well, or additional logic around the specifics of lat/lng.

```
class ApproximateNumberFilter(Filter):
    field_class = FloatField  # use django base float validation

    def __init__(self, under_over=2, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._under_over = under_over

    def filter(self, qs, value):
        if value in EMPTY_VALUES:
            return qs

        return qs.filter(**{
            f"{self.field_name}__gte": value - self._under_over,
            f"{self.field_name}__lte": value + self._under_over,
        })
```

Comment: Should I use this type of filter for latitude and longitude in my filter set class? I created this type of filter but it is not working. Like this:

```latitude = ApproximateNumberFilter(field_name='latitude', )
```
And then I added this simply in fields in meta, Am I following it correctly?

Comment: Yeah, this is generally what I would use.  I haven't tested this specific one, just wrote it up, but its the standard template.  Feel free to send a PM and I'll see if I can help with why it might not be working for you.  Also, you don't need to specify the `field_name` if its the same as the member name, since the filter metaclass will set that for you.

Comment: Ok, tested and it worked ok when filtering my model by PK, so it should be fine.  Something else is going on.